# Passing three dimensional array by reference in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference

Function is defined as:

```
int strip(double *signalstnV){
.
.
return 0;
}
```

And main function it is called as:

```
main{
.
.
double signalstnV[iteration][2*range+1][3];
.
.
check = strip(signalstnV);
.
}
```

I wanted to use the array in next function in main after it is modified in strip function. But during compilation i am getting an error as following

sim.C: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

sim.C:54:26: error: cannot convert ‘double (*)[151][3]’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strip(double*)’

check = strip(signalstnV);

I am not able to understand it. Please help.
My main goal is to generate array from strip function and pass it to other functions later in code.

Also when i used this array in another function

```
threshold(double * signalstnV)
```

and using a for loop to extract some specific values, it gives error as:

```
invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript 
if (signalstnV[k][j][3] < -0.015){
..}
```

Comment: If this is a C++ question then please do not select the "C" tag.  Also please show the definitions of `iteration` and `range`.

Comment: iteration and range are integer constants that i am using throughout the code

Comment: @user3121023 that only works in C, not C++

Comment: This looks pretty much like C to me,

Answer (score 5):

An ordinary single-dimensional array decays to a pointer to its first value. A multi-dimensional array decays only in its first dimension, decaying to a pointer to the initial 2nd dimension of the array.

If you wish to "super-decay" a multi-dimensional array to a pointer to its first value, then simply do that yourself:

```
check = strip(&signalstnV[0][0][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really don't knew this concept.

Comment: using super decay is fine, but now when i used this array in another function threshold(double * signalstnV) and using a for loop to extract some specific values, it gives error as: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript
     if (signalstnV[k][j][3] < -0.015){

Comment: Because it's a pointer, of course, and not a multidimensional array, any more.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's great Sam! but could you show us how to iterate in strip function to print its all elements. (also how to know the size in Strip() definition)?

Answer (score 2):

For such cases, with more or less complicated types - use type aliases:

```
//double signalstnV[iteration][2*range+1][3];
using IterationValues = double[iteration];
using IterationRangesValues = IterationValues [2*range+1];
//...
```

then, it is obvious that calling this:

```
IterationRangesValues signalstnV[3];
check = strip(signalstnV);
```

You need this signature: `strip(IterationRangesValues * matrix)` or this `strip(IterationRangesValues (& matrix)[3])`. Of course for this last array you might use typedef too.

You might also use `std::array`:

```
using IterationValues = std::array<double, iteration>;
using IterationRangesValues = std::array<IterationValues, 2*range+1>;
//...
```

Comment: I thing `std::array` is the best alternative

Comment: @Andrej question is tagged C++

Answer (score 0):

To pass the array by reference, one way is:

```
template<size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z>
int strip( double(&strip)[X][Y][Z] )
{
}
```

Then you can call it with various sizes of array.

If you only need to support the one size, then remove the `template` line and replace `X` `Y` `Z` with the actual dimensions you need to support.